# In a RESTful system, how to make request to a unique server api that doesn't have an id

Tags: rest, ember.js, ember-data

Now my system has some api that doesn't have an unique id, so how to make request from ember data.

Because `find` method needs an id, but i don't have it.

Current, my solution is use pure AJAX call to fetch this kind of data.

So is there have any better solution to make this happen.

Comment: Create an adapter for that model, and override `buildURL` method to always return the URL without the ID. Then call `find` with an ID like `_`, it'll always fetch the URL returned from `buildURL`. http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_buildURL

Comment: Without the ID, is it a RESTful system? Or In an RESTful system, resource must have an ID?

Comment: Well, if you have a singular resource like `/account` there isn't much else you can do other than PUT/POST/GET/DELETE to that URL endpoint...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should be using `DS.RESTSerializer`, if so you could specific custom `primaryKey` for each Model or global to your app.

For Global App.

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer({
  primaryKey: 'customId'
});
```

If your behavior is for a couple model, you do the same for those models.

```
App.MyModel = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attrs('string')
});

App.MyModelSeriliazer = App.ApplicationSerializer.extend({
   primaryKey: 'customId'
});
```

EmberJS would map this `customId` to `id` in ember-data.

Comment: I think you misunderstand my question